# Pymongo returning incorrectly when using "$gte" and "$lte"

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, pymongo, epoch

I'm attempting to select from mongo (using pymongo), querying against epoch timestamps. 
A sample from my database is (pruned for brevity):

```
{
    "_id": "",
    "tweet": {
        "iso_language_code": "en",
        "to_user_name": null,
        "timestamp": 1355325948,
        "created_at": "Wed, 12 Dec 2012 15:25:48 +0000"
    }
}
```

And the query, in code and within python console:

```
<console>
db.tweets.find({
    "tweet.timestamp":{'$gte':1355391000},
    "tweet.timestamp":{'$lte':1355414400}
})

<code>
cursor = db.tweets.find({"tweet.timestamp":{'$gte':startEpoch},
                         "tweet.timestamp":{'$lte':endEpoch}})
```

Which are  *Thu, 13 Dec 2012 09:30:00 GMT* and *Thu, 13 Dec 2012 16:00:00 GMT* respectively.

It should be saying, get me all tweets *gte this int* and *lte this other int*. However, it returns EVERYTHING - it doesn't seem to be limiting the values at all.

For example, this entry is returned, and the timestamp is: *1355325948* which is: *Wed, 12 Dec 2012 15:25:48 GMT*

Also, my understanding that find(...) with a list of params is an implicit AND.

TIA SO!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't have two keys in your query object with the same name.  You have to combine them into a single value like this:

```
cursor = db.tweets.find({"tweet.timestamp":{'$gte':startEpoch, '$lte':endEpoch}})
```